# Calling execute() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

I'm trying to pass my context from one class to another extending `AsyncTask`.
So here's the codes:

```
loadSomeStuff slb = new SamsungLB().new loadSomeStuff();
                        slb.execute(USA.this.getSherlockActivity());
```

AsyncTask:

```
public void execute(SherlockFragmentActivity sherlockActivity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.ctx = sherlockActivity;
        }
```

Then the activity didn't work. So I went to check if the context is null:

```
if (ctx == null) {
                System.out.print("null");
            }
```

Yes I was right, my context is null!
I feel like I'm never calling the execute method :/ any advice?
Here's my full AsyncTask class:

```
public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

ProgressDialog dialog;
Context ctx;

protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.searching));
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //fillinglistview//
    }
    if (ctx == null) {
        System.out.print("null");
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    listview.setAdapter(new MyListAdapterSamsung(getActivity(),
            beanClass));
    if (beanClass.isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "No Connection",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

public void execute(SherlockFragmentActivity sherlockActivity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.ctx = sherlockActivity;
}
}
```

Comment: Don't define an `execute(...)` method for `AsyncTask` (especially if it doesn't call the `super.execute()` method). Just define a constructor which takes an `Activity` or `Context` as its parameter.

Comment: Or change second parameter to Context and pass context by calling native execute method.

Comment: You are not calling `super.execute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a constructor first like this :

```
public loadSomeStuff(SherlockFragmentActivity sherlockActivity) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.ctx = sherlockActivity;
}
```

and don't forget to check if thef fragment alread added or not with

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
   if(isAdded()){
        listview.setAdapter(new MyListAdapterSamsung(getActivity(),
               beanClass));
        if (beanClass.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "No Connection",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }
}
```

and then when you create it :

```
LoadSomeStuff slb = new SamsungLB().new loadSomeStuff(USA.this.getSherlockActivity());
```

then execute just like a normal async task !

```
 slb.execute();
```

I hope my answer can helps you :)

Comment: 08-03 23:51:02.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18758): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SamsungLB{431f97c8} not attached to Activity
 i got this error

Comment: that's where  im extending my asynctask class

Comment: is the ctx still null now?

Comment: Only in OnPostExecute

Comment: please add if(isAdded()){ //YOUR POSTEXECUDTE CODE HERE } in the post execute

Comment: i didn't understand..? can you explain more?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34777/discussion-between-nayoso-and-android-arabia)